# Django Attribute Error - 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'courses'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, genetic-algorithm

I have created different models and in the Division model I am taking reference of many models and their primary key is referenced as a foreign key in Division Model.  I have declared courses as a model attribute in the Batch Model.
This is my models.py file

```
class lab_load(models.Model):
    lab_code = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True) 
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    subject_abv = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    lab_load = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    semester = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    max_numb_students = models.CharField(max_length=65,null=True)
    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(Instructor)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.lab_code} {self.subject_name} {self.subject_abv}'

class Batch(models.Model):
    bat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(lab_load)

    @property
    def get_courses(self):
        return self.courses

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bat_name

class Division(models.Model):
    division_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    num_lab_in_week = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    course = models.ForeignKey(lab_load, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    lab_time = models.ForeignKey(LabTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(LabRoom,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def set_labroom(self, labroom):
        division = Division.objects.get(pk = self.division_id)
        division.room = labroom
        division.save()

    def set_labTime(self, labTime):
        division = Division.objects.get(pk = self.division_id)
        division.lab_time = labTime
        division.save()

    def set_instructor(self, instructor):
        division = Division.objects.get(pk=self.division_id)
        division.instructor = instructor
        division.save()
```

My views.py file

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self._rooms = Room.objects.all()
        self._meetingTimes = MeetingTime.objects.all()
        self._instructors = Instructor.objects.all()
        self._courses = Course.objects.all()
        self._depts = Department.objects.all()
        self._labrooms = LabRoom.objects.all()
        self._labTimes = LabTime.objects.all()
        self._labcourses = lab_load.objects.all()
        self._bats = Batch.objects.all()

    def get_rooms(self): return self._rooms

    def get_labs(self): return self._labs

    def get_labrooms(self): return self._labrooms

    def get_instructors(self): return self._instructors

    def get_courses(self): return self._courses

    def get_depts(self): return self._depts

    def get_labcourses(self): return self._labcourses

    def get_bats(self): return self._bats

    def get_meetingTimes(self): return self._meetingTimes

    def get_labTimes(self): return self._labTimes
```

Under different class: Created class LabSchedule under that I have created function initialize.

```
def initialize(self):
        divisions = Division.objects.all()
        for division in divisions:
            bat = Division.batch
            n = division.num_lab_in_week
            if n <= len(LabTime.objects.all()):
                labcourses = bat.courses.all()    <------ Error in this line ------->
                for labcourse in labcourses:
                    for i in range(n // len(labcourses)):
                        crs_inst = labcourse.instructors.all()
                        newClass = Classlab(self._classNumb, bat, division.division_id, labcourse)
                        self._classNumb += 1
                        newClass.set_labTime(data.get_labTimes()[rnd.randrange(0, len(LabTime.objects.all()))])
                        newClass.set_labroom(data.get_labrooms()[rnd.randrange(0, len(data.get_labrooms()))])
                        newClass.set_instructor(crs_inst[rnd.randrange(0, len(crs_inst))])
                        self._classes.append(newClass)
            else:
                n = len(LabTime.objects.all())
                labcourses = bat.courses.all()
                for labcourse in labcourses:
                    for i in range(n // len(labcourses)):
                        crs_inst = labcourse.instructors.all()
                        newClass = Classlab(self._classNumb, bat, division.division_id, labcourse)
                        self._classNumb += 1
                        newClass.set_labTime(data.get_labTimes()[rnd.randrange(0, len(LabTime.objects.all()))])
                        newClass.set_labroom(data.get_labrooms()[rnd.randrange(0, len(data.get_labrooms()))])
                        newClass.set_instructor(crs_inst[rnd.randrange(0, len(crs_inst))])
                        self._classes.append(newClass)

        return self
```

I am using a genetic algorithm to schedule classes and labs.
Can anyone solve my error it will be helpful, Thank You.

Comment: `bat = Division.batch` did you mean to write `bat = division.batch`? (Notice the capitalization of `d`)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you so much. Sorry this is my mistake and I have posted this question. I m trying so hard to evaluate. But now I am getting error as 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'courses'. Can you please help.

Comment: That simply means that the division has no batch. (You allow that to be possible by setting `null=True` on your foreign key)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have already done that in my Division Model in batch attribute ( null = true). You can view My model in models.py.

Comment: Yes I refer to that exactly. `null=True` simply means you allow that field to have null values. So that means it is possible that an instance of `Division` does not have a related `Batch`. (Which I assume is why you are getting the error, there exists some division which has no related batch)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Once again Thank You. I have removed null=True from my Division model attribute batch. Now it is not giving errors.